# Ask for query to delete data from time to time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a db in sql 2008 with 40 tables:

On each table there is a DateTime column ranging from

2010-01-01 09:00:00.000 up to 2012-01-23 22:00:00.000

I need a query to delete data for all tables only in time range from 17:31:00.000 up to 22:00:00.000

Result would be in having same days as of now but with time range from 09:00:00.000 to 17:30:00.000

Help me regarding this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE CAST(DateTimeColumn AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:31' AND '21:59'
```

For all the tables use this:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable N'DELETE FROM ? WHERE CAST(DateTimeColumn AS TIME) BETWEEN ''17:31'' AND ''21:59'''
```

**But** I have a doubt about that ALL your tables have the same column 8-)

If you want to check what errors appeared during run, try this:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable N'PRINT ''?''; BEGIN TRY DELETE FROM ? WHERE CAST(DateTimeColumn AS TIME) BETWEEN ''17:31'' AND ''21:59''; END TRY BEGIN CATCH PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() END CATCH'
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I have two errors using DELETE
DELETE FROM dbo.tbl1MinBZU (invalid object name, dbo.tbl1MinBZU is my table name)
and
WHERE CAST(DataOra AS TIME)
DataOra =DateTime says invalid column name but these are my table and my column name

Comment: USE StockDataFromSella;
DELETE FROM dbo.tbl1MinBZU;
WHERE CAST(DataOra AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:31:00.000' AND '22:00:00.000'

Now it says sintax not correct for WHERE and for DataOra, suggest SELECT or '('.

Comment: There is semicolon **;** - you not need it there: **DELETE FROM dbo.tbl1MinBZU WHERE CAST(DataOra AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:31:00.000' AND '22:00:00.000'**